# Regex splitting by colon up until a word containing a colon java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split between commands denoted with colons in regex.

I think it's best to explain using an example:

Given the string:

> `alfa bravo charlie:delta echo foxtrot golf:hotel india juliett: kilo`

I want to match the following sections:

`charlie:delta echo foxtrot` `golf:hotel india` and `juliett: kilo`

I am able to match the first one with:

`(\w+:.*?)\s+\w+:.*` and I figure there is someway to check for the final one using `$` but so far I haven't figured out the trick.
If this isn't clear please comment

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use a single `split` call?  I imagine doing `Pattern.compile("\\w+:\\s*\\w+").matcher(s)` followed by repeated `find()` calls would give you the start and end indices of each command.  Much cleaner than a complex lookahead/lookbehind, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match word characters and whitespace character, you could write the pattern as:

```
\w+:\s*\w+(?:\s+\w+)*(?=\s+\w+:|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `\w+:\s*\w+` Match 1+ word chars, `:` optional whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `(?:\s+\w+)*` Optionally repeat 1+ whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `\s+\w+:` Match 1+ whitespace chars followed by 1+ word chars and `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `$` Assert end of string
- `)` Close lookahead

In Java

```
String regex = "\\w+:\\s*\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*(?=\\s+\\w+:|$)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h915Sp/1)

A bit more broader variant:

```
[^\s:]+:.*?(?=\s*[^\s:]+:|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OlpqZ8/1)